# ascx'es javascriptscript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx, user-controls

I want my asp.net .ascx user control to use some javascript. How to do it properly? I am not sure what I should do? Should I use the scriptmanager object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop a script manager on the master page and then:

```
ScriptManager sm = (ScriptManager)master.ScriptManager1;
sm.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("~/Scripts/banners.js"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation.  It's perfectly reasonable just to drop the script into your ascx files.  This is what I do with simple scripts that don't have any sort of dynamic components.  Also good for client-side validatation functions referenced by CustomValidator objects.

For complex scripts it's nice to separate them into their own .js files and link them or add dynamically.